# Checking all values of an array

Tags: swift

Swift 2 - so, I have an array and a uitextfield that a user inputs a string, I want to check whether the textfield.text is equal to ANY of the values in the array, can I do this with one line of code rather than lots of if's and else if's?!?

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic code that will do what you are looking for.  The if statement checks to see if a given value is equal to something that is located in the array.  Simply replace the `arr.contains()` with the output you have given for your UITextfield.text  Try to do a little research before you post.  I can see that you are *new* here, so here is a little bit of help.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4]
if arr.contains(3) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Okay so I understand that but it doesn't really achieve what I want, or at least I can't see it achieving what I want (I'm new to coding) I have an array of around 50 postcodes, a user will input their postcode into a textfield and if their postcode is in the array I want to perform a segue if not show an error label!!

Comment: Provide what you have tried and I will point you in the correct direction.

Comment: I can do a bit later, I currently don't have access to my laptop!!

Comment: So I had a moment of clarity and sorted it, I was totally over complicating it, oops!! I can see that it probably looks like a silly question now :/ however, thanks for your guidance!!